# How can you echo a literal '-n' or '-e'?

Tags: bash, echo, command-line-arguments

In Bash (or really any other shell), if I have an arbitrary string that I want to echo, how can I make it so the echo doesn't come out empty if the string is `-n`, `-e`, or `-E`? I would expect something like `echo -- -e` to work (stopping echo from interpreting any further options), but it doesn't.

Even explicitly specifying a flag doesn't stop it: `echo -E -en` still gives no output.

Is it possible to be safe when using echo, or do I just have to switch all my echo calls to `printf '%s\n'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use:

```
printf "%s\n" "-n"
```

It's simple, safe, reliable, and available most places these days.

Answer (score 2):

Kinda ugly, but this seems to work:

```
echo -e "-\0e"
```

Edit: As suggested by glglgl in the comments, a better solution is

`echo -e '-\0145'` or  `echo -e '-\x65'`

Comment: It only looks as if it would do. `echo -e "-\0e"|hexdump -C` gives me `00000000  2d 00 65 0a`. The `00` is unwanted here. But `echo -e '-\0145'` should do, `0145` being the octal representation of `e`.

Comment: fair point. I'll update the answer.